# Probability of a sum of two random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was reading a probability course, i have difficulties to understand one line of a proof.

X1's CDF is F(We don't know his law).

U1 follows an Uniform distribution U[0,t].

$ P(U_{1} + X_{1} \geq t) = \frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{t} P(U_{1} + X_{1} \geq t | U_{1} = s)ds = \frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{t} (1-F(u))du. $

Any ideas of how we obtain $\frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{t} (1-F(u))du$ in the end?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $$P(U_{1} + X_{1} \geq t | U_{1} = s)=P(s+ X_{1} \geq t | U_{1} = s)=P(X_1\geq t-s)=1-F((t-s)^-)$$ Now, integrate and use the change of variable $u=t-s$.

Comment: For the part $ P(U_{1} + X_{1} \geq t) = \frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{t} P(U_{1} + X_{1} \geq t | U_{1} = s)ds $ Are we using the fact that $ P(U_{1} + X_{1} \geq t) = P(U_{1} + X_{1} \geq t | U_{1} = s) * P(U_{1} \geq s ) $ ?

Comment: @LionheartA. It is not true that $$\mathbb P(U_1+X_1\geqslant t)=\mathbb P(U_1+X_1\geqslant t\mid U_1=s)\cdot\mathbb P(U_1\geqslant s).$$

Comment: Lionheart: In the identity you suggest, what would be $s$ in the RHS? Note that the LHS does not depend on $s$.

Comment: @ Lionheart Please do not omit independence assumptions from your statements. The distribution of the sum of two random variable cannot be determined by their individual distributions in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By conditioning on $U_1$ we compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(U_1+X_1\geqslant t) &= \int_{\mathbb R} \mathbb P(U_1+X_1\geqslant t\mid U_1=s)f_{U_1}(s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \int_0^t\frac1t  \mathbb P(U_1+X_1\geqslant t\mid U_1=s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \frac1t\int_0^t \mathbb P(X_1\geqslant t-s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \frac1t \int_0^t \mathbb P(X_1\geqslant u)\ \mathsf du\\
&= \frac1t \int_0^t \left(1-\lim_{v\to u^-}F(v)\right)\ \mathsf du.
\end{align}
Note that $X_1$ was not assumed to be a continuous random variable, so $F$ need not be continuous - hence the use of the left limit of $F$.